# Compare Nullable DateTime variable for default value

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

In my C# code, I have a `DateTime?` variable. While getting the values from database it can be `null` or can have some date/time value.

On the front end side I don't want to get the default value (01-01-1900 12:00:00 am). Whats the best way to compare my date variable for this default date?

Comment: Does your database actually store `null` for your column?

Comment: No the database stores "01-01-1900" if the value is null.

Comment: Maybe you should have the database store null instead of "01-01-1900"?

Comment: I second Torben. but then again if your database will never use that date then go ahead - no point doing much workaround for a little thing that doesn't bother your app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a const:

```
static readonly DateTime DefaultDateTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

and then compare this way:

```
DateTime? myVariable = returnedFromDb == DefaultDateTime ? default(DateTime?) : returnedFromDb;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have an extension method, something like this:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    static DateTime SQL_DEFAULT = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

    public static bool IsDefaultValue(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime == SQL_DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

And then just test the value:

var isDefault = myDate.IsDefaultValue();